# Use of abstraction in strange way

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class, abstraction, object-oriented-analysis

I have a strange question. Assume there are requirements for two classes (WinRecord, SalesRecord)  like this.

```
WinRecord{
    int won;
    int loss;
    int total;

    //Getters, Setters and other methods.
}

SalesRecord{
    int Sold;
    int Remained;
    int total;

    //Getters, Setters and other methods.
}
```

Is there a nice way to use abstraction (or any other OOP practice) to abstract out these two classes preserving meaningful variable names for each class?

Comment: What do you want to abstract? Name?

Comment: As you said, it's really a strange question... can you be clearer on what you want to abstract ?

Comment: If you noted, both these classes contains similar attributes and behaviors. They are similar in sense of type, usage, return types etc. i.e. other than the names, all the others are similar in usage, logically and operationally. But is their a way to abstract out and isolate that common behavior of them both for reuse?

Comment: Frankly, they have nothing in common apart from the `Record` suffix. There are no behaviours, because you haven't provided any method signatures.

Comment: If you got what I tried to explain, they are logically  similar. Both of them represent a data structure which are related to attributes and behaviors. In both case their is int type1, int type2, int type3 where type3 = type1 + type2. Ex: in 1st one-> type 1: no of wins
                                     type2: no of losses
                                     type3: total no of matches
same as 2nd one. I am asking a way to abstract out  that logic preserving the variable naming. I don't want to use term 'type1'.

Comment: `they are logically similar`- perhaps, but I don't see similarity because I **don't know** what their methods do. `Both of them represent a data structure`- it's a common misconception. Objects are NOT data structures with methods. Objects should represent models with their own state, behaviours and lifetime. Anyway, as I understood from your latest comment, `total` is calculated field, a sum of two other fields. Is this what you saying? If so, you might want to create an abstract class or an interface with `total()` method and implement it in your `record` classes using necessary fields.

Comment: As @AlexeyGroshev has commented, abstraction is more than the structure of data. A class has an intent or a purpose. Class behaviour helps towards the goal and state supports the behaviour. In your example, all we can achieve (*without the behaviour) is an abstract data type -- just find a more generic name that works for both concepts.

Comment: @AlexyGroshev Agree with you.

Comment: @jeyoung fully agree with you. And I would like if you can include your comment as an answer (you may improve), so that I can make that as the answer for my question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I googled and inspected other related questions, answers and comments carefully, the only way is to make an generic class with  generic names for variables. 
But if you want to use the class purely as a data item, it may not be a solution because in case if you want to convert it into a JSON, the variable name will be affected.